# Adding Page Regions to SmartTarget in DXA

Tags: smarttarget, dxa

I'm trying to add a new a new region for a SmartTarget Experiment, following the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v3/GUID-B1678B63-477A-4D1F-9B03-5B87BD865CDF) from LiveContent. However, I believe to have the new Region available in the GUI, I also need to add a `<Region>` entry to the `smarttarget_conf.xml`.

However, the `smarttarget_conf.xml` in my Tridion directory has totally different entries than what I'm seeing in the GUI, so this can't be the correct one. The `smarttarget_conf.xml` in my website has the same entries, but it doesn't seem likely that the GUI would be looking in here. Reinforcing this, updating this file doesn't change the GUI entries. Am I correct that the GUI is reading this from a copy of `smarttarget_conf`, and if so, which copy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should update the list of regions in the `smarttarget_conf.xml` config file in your odata webservice website.
The Smarttarget GUI will regularly update the list of available regions from this webservice.